# Pandas average every ith row of dataframe subset based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```py
id       value
11         0
11         3
11         1
11         2
4          3
4          1
4          8
4          2
5          0
5          3
5          1
5          2
4          2
4          0
4          1
4          3
11         2
11         1
11         0
11         3
```

I'm hoping to average the i_th rows of the N (=4) subsets, that have `id` that are equal; then, end up with the following

```py
id       value
11         1
11         2
11         0.5
11         2.5
4          2.5
4          0.5
4          4.5
4          2.5
5          0
5          3
5          1
5          2
```

e.g. for id=11:

[0+2, 3+1, 1+0, 2+3]/2 = [1, 2, 0.5, 2.5]

Comment: What do you mean by "average the i_th rows"? What is `i`?

Comment: i=1,2,3, or 4, so taking all the subvectors for `id=11` and averaging their components, and giving a single vector out for `id=11` that has 4 elements

Comment: @not_speshal e.g. the mean of the first value of the first 11 group, and the first value of the 2nd 11 group, etc.

Comment: @richardec - Thanks - that's much more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grouper that will group each consecutive group of identical numbers, and then for each group, get a `cumcount` for each group. Then, group by `id` and that cumcount:

```
consecutive_id_grouper = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift(1)).cumsum()
cumcount_grouper = df['id'].groupby(consecutive_id_grouper).cumcount()
avg = df.groupby([df['id'], cumcount_grouper], as_index=False, sort=False)['value'].mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> avg
    id  value
0   11    1.0
1   11    2.0
2   11    0.5
3   11    2.5
4    4    2.5
5    4    0.5
6    4    4.5
7    4    2.5
8    5    0.0
9    5    3.0
10   5    1.0
11   5    2.0
```

Comment: refactored slightly... `avg = df.groupby([df['id'], df['id'].groupby(df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()], as_index=False, sort=False)['value'].mean()` (saves the droplevel and reset_index)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244308/discussion-between-joshp-and-richardec).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach by reshaping and taking the mean.  Would break if there are multiple levels of replicating groups.

```
(df.groupby('id', sort=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x['value'].values.reshape(2,-1).T.mean(1) if len(x)==df.id.value_counts().max() else x['value'].values)
   .explode()
   .reset_index(name='value'))
```

Output

```
    id value
0   11   1.0
1   11   2.0
2   11   0.5
3   11   2.5
4    4   2.5
5    4   0.5
6    4   4.5
7    4   2.5
8    5     0
9    5     3
10   5     1
11   5     2
```